# What phase does CXF WSS4JOutInterceptor get invoked in?

Tags: cxf, ws-security

What is the phase in which the WSS4JOutInterceptor is invoked?
I needed to make some changes to the headers in my custom interceptor.
But since the header is to be encrypted and signed, I need to make my changes before the WSS4JOutInterceptor gets invoked.

I specified in my custom interceptor that it needs to be added before WSS4J:

```
super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);
addBefore(WSS4JOutInterceptor.class.getName());
```

But that did not do it. When my interceptor is invoked, the headers are already signed.
 
I tried READ, PRE_STREAM, USER_STREAM...in all cases, the soap envelope is either empty, or the headers are already encrypted and signed.

How do I position my interceptor to get invoked before WSS4JOutInterceptor?

Update:
I see that the ordering of the interceptors is as follows:

```
setup [PolicyOutInterceptor]
  pre-logical [MAPAggregatorImpl, HolderOutInterceptor, SwAOutInterceptor, WrapperClassOutInterceptor, SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  post-logical [SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor, GZIPOutInterceptor]
  pre-stream [SoapMessageInterceptor, LoggingOutInterceptor, TransformOutInterceptor, AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WSS4JOutInterceptor, MAPCodec]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]
  marshal [BareOutInterceptor]
  post-protocol [WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal]
  post-stream [PolicyVerificationOutInterceptor]
  write-ending [SoapOutEndingInterceptor]
  pre-protocol-ending [SAAJOutEndingInterceptor]
  pre-stream-ending [StaxOutEndingInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]
```

My interceptor (SoapMessageInterceptor) is placed before WSS4JOutInterceptor...but the soap envelope already contains the signature.
How do I get to the headers before WSS4J does?

Comment: I have somewhat similar problem. I cant get outgoing message before encryption.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see above, the WSS4JOutInterceptor is in the "PRE_PROTOCOL" phase. If your interceptor is in "PRE_STREAM" then it should run before the WSS4JOutInterceptor. I don't see how the SoapMessageInterceptor in PRE_STREAM would already see the Signature. Perhaps the message already contains a Signature?

Comment: No, it does not already contain a signature...in fact, if I comment out the WSS4J, the message has no security header at all. So I am a bit confused here ... how could WSS4J get executed before SoapMessageInterceptor?

Answer (score 0):

I will go ahead and guess that your interceptor will override the default XMLStreamWriter and change the content directly.

This however will not work because WSS4JOutInterceptor are signing the content from SAAJ Tree Object instead of the final XML byte. Hence you cannot change your header before the signature process.